# Is the song "Mabel Grey" by Brown Bird an allusion to a real ship?

Tags: song-lyrics, inspiration, allusions

The song [Mabel Grey, by Brown Bird](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-E81QKkid4o) contains peculiar lyrics.

The lyrics are awfully specific about what happened to this ship, which is a common pattern I see when a song is referent to a real-life event. It's reminiscent of Barrett's Privateers, in that it appears like it could be referring to a specific event, and is written in the form of a historical allusion.

But, while Barrett's Privateers is fictional, it contains the details needed to tell a full story. Mabel Grey here seems to be a snapshot of some existing story - its descriptions are both cursory and rather specific, leaving a great number of holes for the listener to either fill in, or, alternately, understand within a pre-existing context.

That leads me to wonder if the Mabel Grey was a real ship and person. There certainly have been both ships and people named "Mabel Grey" (or, Gray). Notably, two schooners that wrecked have borne the name: [one sunk on March 11, 1904, off the coast of California](https://books.google.com/books?id=FqKACQAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=mabel+gray+schooner+sunk&source=bl&ots=UKTGFmZomQ&sig=H3aamc91-ET02pTLCYsn5S-2hpU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4x5Tx0PbUAhVjImMKHXoyDi0Q6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=mabel%20gray%20schooner%20sunk&f=false), and the other [has an entry on ShipIndex, but doesn't seem to have any other public information](https://www.shipindex.org/ships/mabel_gray).

These are my best guesses as to where I would start. But I really have no clue.

Is this song referring to a real event? If not, is it new fabrication, or does it refer to something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to an interview ([link](https://heartstringsmag.wordpress.com/2014/10/05/all-the-right-reasons-an-interview-with-joe-fletcher/)) with surviving band member Joe Fletcher, "Mabel Grey" is in reference to a real ship of the same name, but was written by the late David Lamb and details about the inspiring shipwreck are unknown by anyone except possibly Lamb's wife.

> **Is David Lamb the original writer of that song?**
>   He is. He actually co-wrote it with another friend of mine.
>
> **Do you know the background of that song?**
>   I do know it was an actual ship. From what I’ve read about the ship, it does not sound as though the song was written about that particular story. It was a shipwreck. It was kind of a well-documented shipwreck. I haven’t read anything about it in a long time. [...] I wish now that I would have asked him more about the song. [...] I never really inquired any more deeply, but he had a great imagination. He was very interested in sea stories, just like I am and he worked in a shipyard until he stopped working fully to concentrate on the band. I have a feeling, if I had to guess... I could ask MorganEve about it, she would probably know.

Since Fletcher says the shipwreck was well-documented, I'd guess it's the 1904 California wreck you link in your question.

There's also speculation ([link](https://themetdet.com/at-table-chef-james-rigato/)) that the song references a real woman, Diana of the Dunes ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diana_of_the_Dunes)) AKA Alice Mabel Grey, but that looks like somebody just Googled the name and made assumptions; I can't find any connection to Alice Mabel Grey in the text of the song--the closest is folklore that Diana of the Dunes appears to sailors before a storm ([link](https://books.google.com/books?id=f8UyahyLt20C&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=alice+mabel+grey+AND+malta&source=bl&ots=1tP9kZAfBi&sig=oN4h2UCUVTjvRIlx8WzxDt3ks3c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNwo_Q2fbUAhUBwGMKHdpfCEUQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=alice%20mabel%20grey%20AND%20malta&f=false)).